# Is there a way to use mouseover/hover function to display tooltip under dropdown list for a field in Netsuite?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, netsuite

I am new to this and very curious to know about the way to use mouseover/hover function to display tooltip under the dropdown list for a field in Netsuite

Comment: Pls take a tour here __https://stackoverflow.com/tour__ on how to ask a good community accepted question

Comment: Hi @SaiKiranuppalapati and welcome .. I would suggest you to do your research by looking at articles related to NetSuit here at StackOverflow or by Googling it, and when you have done your reasearch come back here if you have some specific questions related to spe,cific code.

Answer (score 0):

Tool tips natively are only displayed when a user clicks on the name of the field through the UI. I understand one might want customize this using javascript/suitescript; however per NetSuite [Suite Answer Id 43586](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43586/kw/43586) "SuiteScript does not support direct access to the NetSuite UI through the Document Object Model (DOM). The NetSuite UI should only be accessed using SuiteScript APIs."